# Flutter desktop app windows, record package mic works with Bluetooth headphones but not directly with laptop mic

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, audio-recording, microphone, pubspec

We are using record pub package to record a audio and use speech-to-text to convert voice to text for our flutter desktop app. the recording works through Bluetooth headphones. But recording doesn't work with direct mic or wired headphones mic. we cannot force user to use Bluetooth headphones to use our voice assistant. please provide your valuable insights.